# I made a simple discord gif bot, but it keeps sending the same gif when I use the command

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord

So I've made a pretty simple discord bot, when you use the command '/dogggif' it responds with a dog gif. It works but there's an issue, if the user uses the command again I want the bot to respond with another gif of the same topic 'dog',but the bot responds with the same gif.

I've tried using the random module but it doesn't seem to work(or I don't know the right place to put it in) .

In this code I used Tenor's api, but I don't mind using other sites to get gifs.

Note: I am very new to python and this project is just something I thought would be fun to do, so please, if you can, answer with an explanation.

Here's the code:

```
from urllib import response
import hikari
import lightbulb
import requests


bot = lightbulb.BotApp(
    token = 'DicordBotTokenHere', 
    default_enabled_guilds = (123123123) #That should ID of your bot testing server on Discord#
    
)


@bot.listen(hikari.StartedEvent)
async def bot_started(event):
    print('Bot has started!!') #Here it prints something when bot has succesfully started#

@bot.command
@lightbulb.command('doggif','Sends a dog gif!') #We set command's name and description#
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand) #We make it a slash command#
async def dogif(ctx):
    apikey = 'YourTenorApiKeyHere'#You can get the key on tenor's api site#
    def get_gif(search_term):
        responseif =  requests.get("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}&limit=1".format(search_term, apikey))
        data = responseif.json()
        return data['results'][0]['media'][0]['gif']['url']
        
        
        
    await ctx.respond(get_gif('dog'))

    
bot.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
responseif =  requests.get("https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}&limit=1".format(search_term, apikey))
data = responseif.json()
return data['results'][0]['media'][0]['gif']['url']
```

So your functions gives a `.gif` based on a `search_term`.

```
await ctx.respond(get_gif('dog'))
```

So you are always passing the same `search_term`: `'dog'`.

So `Tenor` will always give you the same result, why shouldn't it?

---

If you want it to send a different gif each time, you may want to send a `random` gif:

```
import random
return data['results'][0]['media'][random.randint(1, 10)%10]['gif']['url']
```

In this case you are searching between the first `10` gifs, but if you are sure there are more than `10` gifs of `dog`s on tenor you can change this value.

I guess you'll have to avoid adding `&limit=1` at the end of the `GET` request link:

```
https://g.tenor.com/v1/search?q={}&key={}
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it didn't work because `randint` needs to have an `a` and `b` values inside it, so I tried putting them to 1 and 10, still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you edit your question with the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

I know im late, and probably this isn't what you're looking for, but ive got the same problem a days ago and i made a program to solve it. It is very simple, just a code that print random url's with a specific format that works in discord embed (I mean, it looks good and not deformed). If you want to try it i'll put the code with everything ready right here, so feel free to change everything that you need. Hope it helps :]

```
import requests
import random

apikey = "APIKEY" #PUT YOUR APIKEY HERE.

search_term = "dog"
lmt = 25

r = requests.get("https://tenor.googleapis.com/v2/search?q=%s&key=%s&limit=%s" % (search_term, apikey, lmt))

results = []

if r.status_code == 200:
  gifs = r.json()

  for i in range(lmt):
    gif_format = gifs["results"][random.randint(1, (lmt-1))]["media_formats"]["gif"]
    
    if gif_format["dims"][0] >= gif_format["dims"][1]:
      url = gif_format["url"]
      dims = gif_format["dims"]

      results.append(f"Width = {dims[0]}, Height = {dims[1]}, URL = {url}")
  
  if len(results) > 0:
    print(f"Here are the results for {search_term} ({lmt} url limit) (gif horizontal or square embed discord format): ")
    print(f"Printing 1 random result of {len(results)}")
    print(random.choice(results))

  else:
    print(f"ERROR: There is no results for {search_term}.")

else:
  gifs = None
  print("ERROR: Something failed during the TENOR API request.")
```